# issue with mysql query and optimization into one query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that determine a users rank based on their actions

```
$db->row("SELECT COUNT(ID) as `user_rank` FROM userdetails WHERE (userdetails.totalaction /4) >= ('$user_detailed->totalaction' /4) AND active = 1 AND frozen = 0",array());
```

The above will return there rank and I want to make one query to update all users at once.

Basically I want the `>= ('$user_detailed->totalaction' /4)` to become pure sql no php in the query
so if i had 100 users it will work out each of there ranks and update another field called `current_rank` is it possible to do this all in one query if so can someone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to replace `('$user_detailed->totalaction' /4)` with your desired value to test against. For example if you want it greater than equal 10, then it should be:

```
$db->row("SELECT COUNT(ID) as `user_rank` FROM userdetails WHERE (userdetails.totalaction /4) >= 10 AND active = 1 AND frozen = 0",array());
```

Answer (score 0):

figured out how to do it had to do two queries not one like i wanted ;) thanks for help